# Is there a limit set by the UN of how many troops are allowed in Kashmir?

Tags: kashmir

According to [UN resolutions on Kashmir in the 1950s](https://www.pakungeneva.pk/ContentPage.aspx?ID=20), is there a limit on how many troops Pakistan and India station in their respective occupied territories and if so how high is it?

[India has currently about 700000 regular troops and militias in Kashmir.](https://scroll.in/article/812010/do-you-need-700000-soldiers-to-fight-150-militants-kashmiri-rights-activist-khurram-parvez) How many troops are there from Pakistan as of 2022?

Comment: Do you recall specific UN resolutions?

Comment: @Trilarion, there are dozens of them. I read some, but failed find the number.

Comment: "I read some, but failed find the number." Okay, but still it would be better to link to them, if only to tell others where not to search anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been through the UNSC resolution on Jammu and Kashmir.

They are all over 50 years old, and their relevance today is somewhat doubtful.

None give explicit troop numbers.  The closest is resolution 98 from 1952, which  "*urges* the Governments of India and Pakistan to
enter into immediate negotiations under the auspices of
the United Nations Representative for India and Pakistan
in order to reach agreement on the specific number of
forces to remain on each side of the cease-fire line at the
end of the period of demilitarization, this number to be ,
between 3,000 and 6,000 armed forces remaining on the
Pakistan side of the cease-fire line and between 12,000
and 18,000 armed forces remaining on the India side of
the cease-fire line, as suggested by the United Nations
Representative in his proposals of 16 July 1952."

Do take note of the language as it is significant.  It "urges" the sides (and doesn't "require", or "demand".  It suggests these troop numbers should be agreed as part of "demilitarisation". But the region has moved on since then.

To be honest, I've quoted this but it is completely irrelevant now. The situation is not the same as in 1952, there have been 70 years and several major wars and insurgencies since then, and these numbers were not binding even at in 1952.  There are certainly not binding now!

India currently has 168000 troops, plus an unknown number of police, and irregulars, making the total between 350000 and 700000.  Pakistan has a wider range of soldiers, guerrillas, and militias, plus there are various Islamist groups that support Pakistan, even if they are not supported by Pakistan.  This makes the number of active fighters impossible to estimate.

Short answer:  There are no limits set by the UN.  But both India and Pakistan have substantial numbers of fighters in the region.

Comment: It just means that without the conflict, a large number is people could do something else, potentially more meaningful things. But this is not the case so...